# Displaying images from a RSS feed?

Tags: image, rss

Came across the wikipedia rss feed for their image of the day. I'd like to plug that into a test I'm doing, so their image of the day re displays on this new site. Right now, through using a rss code generator site, I'm able to display only the text. For ex my feed sort of just looks like:

Wikimedia Commons picture of the day for May 17
Picture of the day View of the rich ceiling of the Vank Cathedral in Isfahan, posibly the most impressive christi...

But no photos display. Does anyone know an easy way of adjusting this code I'm using generated from http://www.surfing-waves.com/feed.htm   to display images as well? Thanks much. -Wilson

rss link: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=featuredfeed&feed=potd&feedformat=rss&language=en

code:

```
<!-- start sw-rss-feed code --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
rssfeed_url[0]="https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?        
action=featuredfeed&feed=potd&feedformat=rss&language=en";  
rssfeed_frame_width="180"; 
rssfeed_frame_height="250"; 
 rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
rssfeed_font_face=""; 
rssfeed_border="on"; 
rssfeed_css_url=""; 
rssfeed_title="on"; 
rssfeed_title_name=""; 
rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
rssfeed_title_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_footer="off"; 
rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_item_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
rssfeed_cache = "cb57972543b240ba8193a1b654c72b22"; 
//--> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-        
feed.js"></script> 
<!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people 
find 
the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. --> 
<div style="text-align:right; width:180px;"><a href="http://www.surfing-
waves.com/feed.htm" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">widget     
@</a> <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" target="_blank"             
style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">surfing-waves.com</a></div> 
<!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->
```

Comment: It occurred to me that perhaps php could scrape the image off wiki image of the day page. Though, I'd have to find a way to specify to ONLY pull that singular image, which is above my ability at this moment